# Mouse movement event handler

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, mouse

I'm trying to assign the function below to a variable so I can bind it to another function. Here is this original function

```
var timer = 0;
$(document).ready(function(e)
{
    $(this).on("mousemove", function(e){
        clearTimeout(timer);
        console.log("TRUE mouse");
        timer= setTimeout(function (e) { console.log("false mouse");
        },"5000");

    })
});
```

I tried assigning the above function to this.onMouseHandler, but it doesn't seem to be working. How can I assign the above function to a variable to which I can bind things too?

```
    this.onMouseHandler = function(e )
        {var timer = 0;  
            $(this).on("mousemove", function( e ){
                clearTimeout(timer);
                console.log("true");
                this.active = true;
                timer= setTimeout(function () { console.log("false");
                    this.active = false;
                },"5000");
          }) };
```